# Custom Icons not showing up in Add-on

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

The structure of my add-on files is this:

```
main_folder
    __init__.py
    utils
        operators.py
        ui.py
        props.py
        icons
            icons.png
```

I am handling the loading and deleting of icons in register and unregister of the UI file:

```
custIcons = None

def register():
    global custIcons
    custIcons = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    scriptPath = bpy.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    iconsDir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(scriptPath), "icon.png")
    custIcons.load("icon", os.path.join(iconsDir, "icon.png"), "IMAGE")
```

and

```
def unregister():
    global custIcons
    bpy.utils.previews.remove(custIcons)
```

When I am putting the icon in the UI:

```
def draw(self, context):
    self.layout.label(text = "Test", icon_value = custIcons["icon"].icon_id)
```

When I install the add-on, this shows up:

[image: This is what shows up in the UI.]

Comment: assume  `\__file\__` is a copy paste error? and is it `icon.png` or `icons.png`   It is my understanding that `__file__` is an abs path.  Wont be the value you want if you run it from the __main__ thread.

Comment: Yes, \\_\_file\\_\_ and icons.png was an error. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

`bpy.utils.previews.new()` aka `ImagePreviewCollection` 's `.load(...)` needs an absolute file path, as relative file paths to work reliably.

````py
def load(prefix, icon_name):
    global custIcons

    name = os.path.splitext(icon_name)[0]
    # abspath is needed for .load to work reliably
    filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(prefix, icon_name))
    custIcons.load(name, filename, 'IMAGE')
```
````